What should be done to finish or improve this retaining wall?
This was installed by a previous owner. I have gotten some feedback that it's unfinished and not typical of a retaining wall, but I don't know what needs to be done to finish it. For example, what is the purpose of the fence posts?



upvote to brhans for attaching the pics.

The posts are holding the wood that is doing the retaining of the stone.
Wood usually does not last long enough outside for that job.
The blocks are just placed there for maybe hiding the wood/posts.  The blocks right now do nothing else.
This is a pro job to prevent the whole thing from collapsing in time.
Knowing the original idea/purpose of this might help to decide to finish or remove.  Removal should be much cheaper if the materials are used/given to contractor for a reduced price.
The removal, if chosen can be a DIY job, if the weight(stones, and whatever is under them is removed first.  The wood and blocks will be easy to remove after.

Agreed. This is a poorly done retaining wall that is doomed to collapse.
